# What is the meaning of data-driven in context of Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

What is the meaning of data-driven in context of Reactjs? Does data-driven mean [`data-driven programming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming)? How does it make sense?

Can anybody explain it with an example?

Comment: Can you show where you read "data-driven" in relationship to React?

Comment: [Relay Framework's page](https://facebook.github.io/relay/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Data-driven" means that the lifecycle of the application (when views are rendered, when they update, which parts of the UI update etc) are all driven by the flow of the data through the application. User interactions trigger data updates and other possible side-effects, that then flow back through the user interface.

A similar, useful label that you could apply would be "data-intensive". Modern apps manage large quantities of frequently-changing data, displayed in complex UIs, and users expect the different parts of the UI to remain in sync and consistent, and to update in a timely fashion. This is a data-intensive application model, and that's the main use case that Relay is trying to solve for.

I went through some of this design philosophy in my "[Relay Deep Dive](https://youtu.be/oPSuvaYmXBY)" talk.